# Category pages htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, pagination

I have a problem with the pagination of the category page

**htaccess**

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule .  - [L]
RewriteRule ^kategorija/(.*)/(.*)$ category.php?category=$1&page=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^kategorija/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/?$ category.php?category=$1 [L]
```

Using different URLs results in different results:

- http://fbquizz.com/katalogas/kategorija/televizoriai-internetu/ This shows only title page (with ending slash!)
- http://fbquizz.com/katalogas/kategorija/televizoriai-internetu Everything is fine (without ending slash!) x

What is wrong?

Comment: You tell us what is wrong by stating what happens. Error? Loads the wrong page/content?

Comment: I dont no what error, televizoriai-internetu showed product,  and / televizoriai-internetu/ not show product....  televizoriai-internetu/1/ okey pagination

Comment: Why did you include the `/` in the latter charclass? It's already optionalized per `/?$`. - Also the preceding `(.*)/(.*)` is too crude. That would match anything ending in a `/` slash.

Comment: Now i have error Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in